# Determining if infinite series of increasing derivatives is a continuous functional

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $D(\mathbb{R})$ be the space of test functions on $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. the set of smooth compactly supported functions on $\mathbb{R}$, and where we say $\phi_k \to \phi$ if $\phi_k$ and all its derivatives converge uniformly to $\phi$.

Question: Is the functional on $D(\mathbb{R})$ defined by $T(\phi)=\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\phi(\frac{1}{n})$ continuous?

If I look at $\vert T(\phi_k) - T(\phi)\vert$ I get a series $\vert \phi_k'(1) - \phi'(1)\vert + \vert \phi''(\frac{1}{2}) - \phi''(\frac{1}{2})\vert + \vert \phi_k'''(\frac{1}{3})-\phi'''(\frac{1}{3})\vert$. I thought I could maybe find some creative choice of $\epsilon_n$ for which $\vert \phi_k^n(\frac{1}{n}) - \phi^n(\frac{1}{n})\vert < \epsilon_n$ for $k>N\in \mathbb{N}$ which makes the series converge to less than $\epsilon$, but I'm not sure how to actually do this (or if it's even possible). Any insight on how to attack the above question would be helpful.

Comment: The above definition of convergence $\phi_k\rightarrow \phi$ is not correct. One needs the existence of a compact $K$ which contains the support of all these functions.

Answer (score 1):

The series in the definition of $T$ is not even convergent on $D(\mathbb{R})$. To see that consider $\phi (x)=\varphi(x)\sin x$, where $\varphi\in D(\mathbb{R})$ is such that $\varphi\equiv 1$ on $(0,1)$. Then $T(\phi)=T(\sin x)$ and note that for every $n$ odd we have
$$
\Big|\frac{d^n\sin}{dx^n}(1/n)\Big|=|\cos(1/n)|\ge |\cos(1/2)|=1/\sqrt{2}, \qquad n\ge 2.
$$

Comment: I know it doesn't converge in general, but I'm not sure how to show it does/doesn't for the specific case of $\vert T(\phi_k)-T(\phi)\vert$

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to verify whether $|T(\phi_k)-T(\phi)|\rightarrow 0$ if $\phi_k\rightarrow \phi$ in $D(\mathbb{R})$. If, so then upon taking $\varphi_k:=\phi_k-\phi$ and using the linearity of $T$ the question becomes: does $T(\varphi_k)\rightarrow 0$ if $\varphi_k\rightarrow 0$ in $D(\mathbb{R})$. This however is false. Consider $\varphi_k(x)=e^{-kx}$. Clearly $\varphi_k$ converges to $0$ in $D(\mathbb{R})$, but for every fixed $k$ the series defining $T(\varphi_k)$ is divergent, so $T(\varphi_k)$ is not even defined.